# Can caffe reshape layer do transpose

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

`Caffe` have `reshape` layer implemented, but say I want to first reshape a blob of `(1, n, k, p)` to `(1, a, b, k, p)`, where `n= a*b` and then transpose it to shape `(1, b, a, k, p)`, how to implement this operation, I know I can write a seperate python layer and do all this with `numpy.reshape` and `numpy.transpose`, but that would be not efficient, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`transpose` and `reshape` are two **fundamentally** different operations:
While `reshape` only changes the shape of a blob, it does not affect its internal structure (and thus can be execute very efficiently). On the other hand, `transpose` re-arrange the blob's data.

Let's look at a simple example.
Suppose you have a 2x2 blob with values

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

In memory the values are stored in a 1D contiguous way (row-major):

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

If you `reshape` the blob to 4x1

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
```

The underlying arrangement of the elements in memory is not changed.
However, if you `transpose` the blob to get

```
[[0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

The underlying arrangement is also changed to

```
[0, 2, 1, 3]
```

Therefore, you **cannot** use `"Reshape"` layer to `transpose` a blob.

Caffe SSD branch (by [Weilu](http://cs.unc.edu/~wliu/)) has a [`"Permute"`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/commit/b68695db42aa79e874296071927536363fe1efbf) layer which is equivalent to `transpose`.

**A note about performance:**
While `reshape` only changes the blob's header (`O(1)` runtime and space), `transpose` needs to re-arrange elements in memory thus taking `O(n)` time and space.
To make things worse, if you use **`numpy.transpose`** to perform the task it means you `transpose` in CPU (host memory) thus adding two sync operations between CPU and GPU memory (sync GPU->CPU, transpose in CPU, sync CPU->GPU).
So, if you have no alternative but to `transpose` (aka `"Permute"`) make sure you have a GPU implementation.