# Matrix multiplication (element-wise) from numpy to Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I got two numpy arrays (image and and environment map),

```
MatA
MatB
```

Both with shapes `(256, 512, 3)`

When I did the multiplication (element-wise) with numpy:

```
prod = np.multiply(MatA,MatB)
```

I got the wanted result (visualize via Pillow when turning back to Image)

But when I did it using pytorch, I got a really strange result(not even close to the aforementioned).

I did it with the following code:

```
MatATensor = transforms.ToTensor()(MatA)
MatBTensor = transforms.ToTensor()(MatB)

prodTensor = MatATensor * MatBTensor
```

For some reasons, the shape for both MatATensor and MatBtensor is

```
torch.Size([3, 256, 512])
```

Same for the prodTensor too.
When I tried to reshape to `(256,512,3)`, I got an error.

Is there a way to get the same result?

I am new to pytorch, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation of [`transforms.ToTensor()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor) you'll see this transformation does not only convert a numpy array to `torch.FloatTensor`, but also transpose its dimensions from `H`x`W`x`3` to `3`x`H`x`W`.
To "undo" this you'll need to

```
 prodasNp = (prodTensor.permute(2, 0, 1) * 255).to(torch.uint8).numpy()
```

See [`permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @Shai for the answer. I finally managed to solve it by reshaping the Matrices in 2d (w*h,3). I will confirm your solution soon

Comment: @alphjheon note that there is a *fundamental* difference between `permute` and `view`: while `view` changes the shape of the tensor it does *not* affect the actual arrangement of elements. In contrast, `permute` re-order the elements of the tensor. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48397218/1714410) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.from_numpy), which will easily convert your `ndarray`s to torch tensors. As in:

```
In[1]: MatA = np.random.rand(256, 512, 3)
In[2]: MatB = np.random.rand(256, 512, 3)

In[3]: MatA_torch = torch.from_numpy(MatA)
In[4]: MatB_torch = torch.from_numpy(MatB)

In[5]: mul_np = np.multiply(MatA, MatB)
In[6]: mul_torch = MatA_torch * MatB_torch

In[7]: torch.equal(torch.from_numpy(mul_np), mul_torch)
Out[7]: True

In[8]: mul_torch.shape
Out[8]: torch.Size([256, 512, 3])
```

If you want it back to numpy, just do:

```
mul_torch.numpy()
```